# installed oqtane imageflow succesfully but querystrings have no effect on image

Tags: imageflow

i have successfully installed oqtane imageflow (confirmed by accessing the diagnistics page) but when i add quesrystring parameters to my url nothing happens? Do i need to set some kind of mapping for imageflow to know where my files are? for example when i try to access http://localhost:44357/files/ssdp-logo-v2-web.png?w=10&quality=1 The image is returned but either of the querystring parameters have been applied to the image.

I am using the module in oqtane but not 2sxc

Thanks

I was expecting the image to be resized and returned with low quality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of Imageflow and Imageflow Server. Typically, yes, you'll map prefixes to the filesystem or blob storage.

I'm not the author of the Oqtane adapter for Imageflow, so keep that in mind. If [this code is running](https://github.com/2sic/oqtane-imageflow/blob/main/Src/Server/Startup.cs), then the 'wwwroot' folder should be mapped to /

Is your file in wwwroot/files/ ?

Comment: note: if you think a question needs more detail/clarity, you are discouraged from answering it until that detail/clarity is added. see [answer].

Comment: I think people have been sufficiently discouraged from using StackOverflow already, TBH, it's in death throes and only genuine helpfulness can save it.

Comment: you can help genuinely in comments to clarify the question, and then genuinely help by answering the clarified question!

Comment: I'm not going to withhold a generally useful answer just to extract a small extra bit of data that is unique to the OP and may or may not be relevant. Also, edits exist.